# SQL - Select only when the condition matches

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, select

I have a table like below.

```
ID   NAME
1    JOHN
2    JANE
3    JACK
```

In a simple select statement, how can I query JOHN and JANE from the table?

The conditions are:

i. Result has to return JOHN and JANE.

ii. If either JOHN or JANE been deleted from the table, it will just returns empty result.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework

Comment: -1 No evidence of what you've tried, what you're having trouble with etc.  No problem asking homework questions, but at least have a crack at it yourself before asking your staff to do it for you.

Comment: please show some efforts... what have you tried?

Comment: Why have you tagged with `Oracle`, `Postgresql` and `MySQL`. Which one are you using?

Comment: No this not a homework. This question just occurred to me when I was peer-reviewing codes with my colleague. Yes this can be achieved by joining the same table or using group by. But we were looking for much simpler query. Sorry guys for straight forward question without any insufficient info

Comment: @user2285851 If you didn't want answers that involved joining the same table or using group by, and you were looking for a much simpler query, it would have been _sufficient_ to say so.

Comment: Is NAME a UID?  Or can you have more than one JANE?

Comment: Also what is the reason for the apparently arbitrary ban on GROUP BY or self joins, as those are pretty much the simplest way of acheiving what you want.  Real world reason pleasde, or else this is just "Code golf" and as such off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `GROUP BY/HAVING` to ensure there are 2 matches:

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    T
WHERE   Name IN ('JOHN', 'JANE')
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T
            WHERE   Name IN ('JOHN', 'JANE')
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT Name) = 2
        );
```

Or you could use a self join:

```
SELECT  a.Name
FROM    T a
        INNER JOIN T b
            ON a.Name != b.Name
WHERE   a.Name IN ('JOHN', 'JANE')
AND     b.Name IN ('JOHN', 'JANE');
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle (MySQL)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/055bd/8)**

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle (Oracle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b895c/1)**

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle (Postgresql)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/021b5/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( `NAME` ) as names
FROM `TABLE`
WHERE 1
   AND NAME IN ('JOHN','JANE')
HAVING names= 'JOHN,JANE'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Function `JohnAndJaneBothExist()`

2.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE
  JohnAndJaneBothExist and
  Name In ('John', 'Jane')
```